# Can't run kube-apiserver --enable-admission-plugins=DefaultStorageClass

Tags: kubernetes, kube-apiserver

After installation three node cluster
https://kubernetes.io/docs/setup/independent/create-cluster-kubeadm/

I've entered into ApiServer container using

```
sudo docker exec --user root -it 1ea54fd4cd683 /bin/sh
```

and executed

```
kube-apiserver --enable-admission-plugins=DefaultStorageClass
```

but it writes

> I0923 14:37:58.270848      90 server.go:703] external host was not
>   specified, using 192.168.41.29 W0923 14:37:58.271386      90
>   authentication.go:378] AnonymousAuth is not allowed with the
>   AlwaysAllow authorizer. Resetting AnonymousAuth to false. You should
>   use a different authorizer Error: --etcd-servers must be specified

Could smb say why it happens and how fix it?

Comment: What version of `kubeadm` do you use?

Answer (score 2):

First of all, I'm pretty sure that's not the recommended way to add flags to the apiserver.
Those changes will not persist.
You probably want to edit `/etc/kubernetes/manifests/kube-apiserver.json` on the master, kill the kube-apiserver pod, and wait for it to respawn.

I'm guessing here, but try adding `--anonymous-auth=false` ?